# Eclipse 3.5.2 doesn't have EclipseMarketPlace?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I don't find the Eclipse Market Place tab under the help in Eclispe 3.5.2 (Galileo). Are they not available on Eclipse 3.5.x builds?

Comment: "Are they not unavailable" == "Are they available"

Comment: thanks for the dictionary. I am looking for an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro) is included with all of the Eclipse 3.6 packages, except Eclipse 3.6 classic.

Comment: So, in particular, it is correct to say that Eclipse MarketPlace client is not available in Eclipse 3.5.x. This feature wasn't implemented until Eclipse 3.6.

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik: It appears so.  I couldn't find a plug-in on the Eclipse Marketplace web site.

Comment: Thank you Gil and Konstantin. This feature is not available on 3.5.x